# Microsoft SQL Server Mangement Studio gives error when trying to add device for restoring backup

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express

Yes in Management studio I am trying to restore a backup from another server.  So I am doing the following:

- This is a fresh install of SQL Server 2017 express

1. Right Click on the Databases Folder and choose restore database.
2. Then I click on Device and the ... button to the right
3. I click on add for the file and then this error shows up, I never even get to choose the file so I don't think its a file permission on the file like I have seen elsewhere.

[image: Picture of All The Screens separated with the Error]

## Show Details..

Failed to retrieve data for this request. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc)

---

For help, click: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&LinkId=20476

---

Program Location:

at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.Enumerator.Process(Object connectionInfo, Request request)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.BrowseFolderBase.d__1.MoveNext()
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.BrowseFolderEx.FillDrives()
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.BrowseFolderEx.Initialize()
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.BrowseFolderBase.Init(Boolean force)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.BrowseFolderBase.Init()
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlManagerUI.SqlRestoreSelectBackupSource.AddFile()
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlManagerUI.SqlRestoreSelectBackupSource.buttonAdd_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)

===================================

An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)

---

Program Location:

in Program Location I see this:
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.Enumerator.Process(Object connectionInfo, Request request)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.BrowseFolderBase.d__1.MoveNext()
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.BrowseFolderEx.FillDrives()
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.BrowseFolderEx.Initialize()
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.BrowseFolderBase.Init(Boolean force)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.BrowseFolderBase.Init()
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlManagerUI.SqlRestoreSelectBackupSource.AddFile()
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlManagerUI.SqlRestoreSelectBackupSource.buttonAdd_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)

I noticed it says "at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.BrowseFolderBase.d__1.MoveNext()"  I do have a D drive that is a raid array connected to this server is that referencing the d drive by chance or am i just reading that wrong?

Comment: "Show details" might be helpful.

Comment: I also found this when i click show details on the message screen... Failed to retrieve data for this request. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc) which i'm trying to google now

Comment: i have searched and searched and getting no where so if anyone has any suggestions i would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Can you show us each of those dialogs without the other ones covering them? I don't know what might be covered up, but it might give someone an idea. I can't think of what in the restore process would overflow an integer data type. I wouldn't think you have more than 2 billion files in a directory. :-)

Comment: Yeah  I can they are the default because the only box that is behind the error is where you choose either add by file or url like i said i don't even get to choose a file ass soon as i click add this error pops up.. i will try to update this ticket in the next hour.  Thanks

Comment: updated the question and it has a link that shows all the windows to give the full picture.

Comment: When I follow the same steps, I get a file/directroy picker with a starting point of the default backup location. (F:\MSSQL\Backup\ in my case. It can be found in the Server Properties dialog, on the Database Settings page.) Perhaps you have so many files in that directory that the dialog overflows a variable when trying to iterate through them. Manually check the contents of your default backup location. And maybe try changing it to a known empty directory and see if you can get farther.

Comment: So when I click on the Properties and go to Database Settings and click on the ... dots to choose the path I get the same error... anytime i have to open anything with a path it seems to throw that errors.  I have no sql backups in the default place as well.

Answer (score 0):

brought up a 2019 server, installed sql express 2017 and everything seems to work.. thinking it might be corrupt files on the old server and just not worth my time to figure that out right no.